# Must 2 JMS providers hold the context class of each other to communicate?

Tags: jms, weblogic

We'll start with a down-to-earth example and then return the coneptual question.

I am using Weblogic (10.3) as my Application Server. I want my application to have JMS capabilities and decided to let it use the Weblogic as the JMS / MOM provide. I setup a Queue in Weblogic and created an MDB class in my code.

Now I want to send a message to Weblgic queue. I used openJMS client. It required me to include the weblogic jar file in its classpath in order to send a message to weblogic.

And the same when I setup Weblogic to send message to the openJMS queue - I used Foreign Destination - it threw class not found exception until I placed openJMS jars in weblogic classpath.

This is becasue all JMS communication examples I saw use JNDI context to get the connection factory.

**My question is:** does that make sense? Isn't JMS suppose to be some neutral communication protocol? Meaning I can't decide to which JMS provider I am sending, at run-time, because I won't have its context classes in my classpath?

Or did I simply miss something in the setup?

Is there another way to preapre the connection factory to the remote provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Isn't JMS suppose to be some neutral communication protocol?

Good question. The answer is: it isn't. JMS is only the API that defines how to connect and send messages to queues/topics. It is not a protocol, so JMS provider implementations are free to use their own internal message format — that's why you need to import the jars of the provider. And also you can't expect provider A to be able to exchange messages with provider B, unless both providers give such possibility explicitly.

An open, cross platform messaging communication protocol is [AMQP](http://www.amqp.org). There are also other commercial solutions, for example IBM Websphere MQ.

Comment: Finally a coherent answer. Thanks. Just to be clear - is MQ cross platfrom because other JMS providers don't need to import its liberaries, or because it has liberaries to all platforms?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I was looking for suporting examples of this. Now I voted. Can you just clarify (or point to the right direction) - is MQ cross platfrom because other JMS providers don't need to import its liberaries, or because it provides liberaries to all platforms?

Comment: @OmegaZiv No problem, I sometimes point it out to new users, I'm not pressed for time :) By "cross platform" I mean not limited to JMS, but also not limited to Java. Both Websphere MQ and Apache QPID have libraries for different OSes and languages, e.g. Java, C++, Python, Ruby, even Cobol. Because they follow a protocol, application from different architectures understand each other.